# MYSQL get latest 10 rows but also include a row which may not in the 10 newest

Tags: mysql

A table have 1000 rows with id from 1 to 1000.

I would like to get the latest 10 rows (e.g. 990 to 1000), but in the *same query* include the row with id = 500

(it's ok to have 11 rows returned - if that's helps)

Any suggestions?

Comment: What if there is no row with id 500, what do you want to happen?

Comment: Well in my case it doesn't matter. I guess it's a classic web app problem - e.g. having a html select, which should not include all 1000 rows only say 10 rows and the one that is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I'd order by the ID being equal to 500 and then by the ID descending, and then limit the results to 11 rows:

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     mytable
ORDER BY id = 500 DESC, id DESC
LIMIT    11
```